# Web API Dynamic Enable/Disable Response

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I want to be able turn on/off all my web api routes based on a user defined boolean value. For now this can come from Web.config. If this flag is set to false I want to be able to respond to any request (any and all routes weather valid or not) with an error message -- "..api is disabled..."

Just toying with the idea here of overriding the controller's Initialize method with some psuedo code. I guess this would assume though that the route being requested is valid where I want to response to any requests what so ever. I'm not even sure if I can inject an IsEnabled property into the Configuration.Properties collection.  Looking for any recommendations how I can shut down the routing and respond accordingly based on a setting.

Thanks

```
 public class MyController : ApiController
    {
        protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
        {
            if (!Convert.ToBoolean(controllerContext.Configuration.Properties["IsEnabled"]))
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Api is currently disabled."));
            }
            base.Initialize(controllerContext);
        }
```

EDIT: Possible use HttpConfiguration.MessageHandlers.Add() to intercept all request(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a custom [DelegatingHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.delegatinghandler(v=vs.118).aspx)

```
internal class BaseApiHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);

        var allowRequest = //web config value

        // if request is allowed then let it through to the next level
        if(allowRequest)
            response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        // set response message or reasonphrase here

        // return default result - forbidden
        return response;
   }
}
```

Edit your **webapiconfig.cs** to include this route at the top

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Default",
    routeTemplate: "{*path}",
    handler: HttpClientFactory.CreatePipeline
    (
        innerHandler: new HttpClientHandler(),
        handlers: new DelegatingHandler[] { new BaseApiHandler() }
    ),
    defaults: new { path = RouteParameter.Optional },
    constraints: null
);
```